# Splitting columns using pivot_table

Tags: python, pivot-table

What is the function i need to Split or Unstack rows into columns in Python please? I need my data to go from this:

```
AreaCode | Type        | Disag    | Value 
101      | Numerator   | Total    | 10
101      | Denominator | Total    | 20
102      | Numerator   | Total    | 55
102      | Denominator | Total    | 65
```

to this 4 column table:

```
AreaCode | Disag | Denominator | Numerator  
101      | Total | 10          | 20
102      | Total | 55          | 65
```

This is the code to import the first table:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'AreaCode' : ['101', '101', '102', '102'],
            'Type' : ['Numerator', 'Denominator', 'Numerator', 'Denominator'],
            'Disag' : ['Total', 'Total', 'Total', 'Total'],
            'Value' : [10, 20, 55, 65]}

Data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['AreaCode', 'Type', 'Disag', 'Value'])
```

How do i make it look like i want please? So far all I can come up with is this:

```
Data = Data.pivot_table(values = 'Value',
                        index = ['AreaCode', 'Disag'],
                        columns = 'Type')
```

which creates a table with only two columns (Numerator and Denominator), and then some indexes. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
Data = Data.pivot_table(index='AreaCode', columns=['Type', 'Disag']).stack(level='Disag')
Data.columns = Data.columns.get_level_values(1)
print(Data.reset_index())
```

To print:

```
Type AreaCode  Disag  Denominator  Numerator
0         101  Total           20         10
1         102  Total           65         55
```

---

EDIT: To save to CSV, you can do:

```
Data = Data.pivot_table(index='AreaCode', columns=['Type', 'Disag']).stack(level='Disag')
Data.columns = Data.columns.get_level_values(1)
Data = Data.reset_index()

Data.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)  # <-- save it to CSV
```

This will save to CSV like this:

[image]

Comment: this looks perfect on-screen thanks - is there any way I can write this into the table so my df 'Data' is permanently formatted in this way for purposes of exporting to csv?